# Biblatex uses shorthand as reference in text

Tags: biblatex, pdftex

I'm using biblatex with biber for my references. No matter which citation style I choose, the shorthand of the reference is always used. I have tried both authoryear and numeric. In multiple attempts. I have also used the following compilation loop: Latex, biber, 2x Latex. I am clueless on how to proceed to fix the problem.

Here is my code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,ngerman,numbers=enddot]{article}
\usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel} % Neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Zeichensatz
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Schriftart
\usepackage{setspace} % Zeilenabstand
\onehalfspacing % 1,5 Zeilen
\usepackage{microtype} % mikrotypographische Optimierungen
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliographie.bib}

\begin{document}
    This is a test. \cite{UnitedNations.12.2015}
\end{document}
```

Bibliography Entry:

```
@misc{UnitedNations.12.2015,
 year = {12.2015},
 title = {Paris Agreement},
 url = {https://unfccc.int/sites/default/files/english_paris_agreement.pdf},
 urldate = {2021-10-17},
 editor = {{United Nations}},
 abstract = {},
 location = {Paris},
 shorthand = {Paris},
 file = {english{\_}paris{\_}agreement:Attachments/english{\_}paris{\_}agreement.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

BLG-File:

```
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
[0] Config.pm:314> INFO - Logfile is 'Vorlage Hausarbeiten.blg'
[145] biber-MSWIN64:340> INFO - === 
[202] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'Vorlage Hausarbeiten.bcf'
[360] Biber.pm:952> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[383] Biber.pm:4340> INFO - Processing section 0
[398] Biber.pm:4531> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bibliographie.bib' for section 0
[450] bibtex.pm:1689> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[556] bibtex.pm:1494> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibliographie.bib'
[593] Utils.pm:395> WARN - legacy year field '12.2015' in entry 'UnitedNations.12.2015' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
[610] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[610] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[610] Biber.pm:4168> INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nyt' and locale 'de-DE'
[610] Biber.pm:4174> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
[617] bbl.pm:654> INFO - Writing 'Vorlage Hausarbeiten.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[618] bbl.pm:757> INFO - Output to Vorlage Hausarbeiten.bbl
[619] Biber.pm:128> INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

Here is a picture of the outcome in the PDF:

[image: Picture of the outcome]

Comment: Make a small but complete example.  show also the bib-entry and the content of the blg-file.

Comment: show the output of the biber run. It should have some more information about the used bibdata file and the cities

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are asking about, this is kind of the point of the `shorthand` field. This field is supposed to override any automatically generated label. It is used in case you want to refer to an entry via a different label than the usual one. This is particularly in areas where certain often-cited works have 'fixed' names.

Comment: Data added as you requested.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but `style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear` is equivalent to `style=authoryear,`. `year = {12.2015},` may cause sorting issues, use `date = {2015-12},` instead.

Comment: @moewe Thank you very much.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

The `shorthand` field can be used to force a particular citation label more or less independent of the style. It will take precedence over the label automatically generated by the style that you would see otherwise.

The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) explains the field as follows

> `shorthand` field (literal)//Label field
>
> A special designation to be used by the citation style instead of the usual label. If defined, it overrides the default label.

In your example you probably don't want to set `shorthand` to `Paris`. Depending on what you are looking for, drop the `shorthand` field completely or use something slightly more useful like `shorthand = {Paris Agreement},`.